# SQL - many to many - how to do it in one query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, subquery

If i have a db like this with 3 tables:

```
Table: BlogEntries
BlogEntries.id (pk)
BlogEntries.blogText

Table: Tags
Tags.id (pk)
Tags.TagName

Table: TagsForBlogEntries
TagsForBlogEntries.id (pk)
TagsForBlogEntries.tag_id
TagsForBlogEntries.entry_id
```

if i want to get a list of blog entries and get the data like this (expressed as an array):

```
array (
[0] => array(
    [id] => '1',
    [blogText] => 'example text',
    [tags] => array(
      array([id]=>1, [TagName] => 'A Test Tag 1'),
      array([id]=>2, [TagName] => 'A Test Tag 2'),

    )
),
```

(ie with all the tags). how is the best way to do this?

I currently would do this (pseudo code) - basically run a sub query 'manually' (not from the original sql query):

```
select * from BlogEntries;
$rows =array();
foreach($blogEntries as $row) {

   $row['tags'] = mysql_fetch_array( mysql_query("select * from Tags left join TagsForBlogEntries on TagsForBlogEntries.tag_id = tags.id where entry_id = " . $row['id'] ) ) ;
   $rows[] = $row;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways.  One is to group by the blog post:

```
SELECT be.id, blogText, GROUP_CONCAT(TagName) AS tags
FROM BlogEntries be JOIN TagsForBlogEntries tbe ON (be.id = tbe.entry_id)
JOIN Tags ON (tbe.tag_id = Tags.id)
GROUP BY be.id
```

When you iterate over each row, you can split the `tags` column by comma (or use your own `SEPARATOR` with `GROUP_CONCAT`.

The second would be similar to the above, but you do the aggregation yourself.  No `GROUP BY`.

```
while ($row = $result->fetch()) {
    if (!isset($blogs[$row['id']]) {
        $blogs[$row['id']] = array(
            'text' => $row['blogText'],
            'tags' => array()
        );
    }
    $blogs[$row['id']]['tags'] = $row['TagName'];
}
```